# __init__ being called on __str__ result in aenum.Enum

Tags: python, python-3.x, enumeration

While trying silly things to get my `__str__` method working correctly on an Enum member, I discovered some behavior I don't really understand.  I'm aware the following implementation is wrong, but I don't know why it does what it does.

Consider the following class:

```
from aenum import Enum, AutoValue
class MyEnum(str, Enum, settings=AutoValue, init="value data1 data2"):

    __str__ = lambda self: self

    def __new__(cls, name, *args, **kwargs):
        member = str.__new__(cls)
        member._value_ = name
        return member

    @staticmethod
    def _generate_next_value_(name, *args, **kwargs):
        return (name,) + args

    member1 = 1, 2
    member2 = 3, 4
```

On import, this works as exected. `MyEnum.member1.data1 == 1` and `MyEnum.member1.data2 == 2`.  However, when I call `str(MyEnum.member1)` an exception is thrown saying "missing value for 'data2'".  I traced through the code here and it seems `MyEnum.member1.__str__().__init__(MyEnum.member1.__str__())` is being called.  I'm not positive that's the call path, but that's the result. And since `MyEnum.__init__ is Enum.__init__` and we're using AutoValue, the **init** method is expecting two arguments.  It's trying to set `member1.data1 = member1` and `member1.data2` doesn't have a value.

To be clear, I'm aware the correct solution is to implement the `__str__` method as `__str__ = str.__str__`.  However, since `isinstance(MyEnum.member1, str) == True`, and `__str__` needs to return a `str`... I'm unclear why the above implementation would behave how it does.

1. Why is any `__init__` getting called?
2. Why is it insufficient to return `self` since `self` is an `str`?
3. Unrelated somewhat, by why could I not implement this without setting "value"? If you take away, value from the init string, remove the `__new__` and `_generate_next_value_` methods, on import a `TypeError` is thrown saying `str() argument 2 must be str, not int` (.../aenum/**init**.py:1302).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @Prune That makes sense, my bad.  My question was more about usage, so I figured posting the example and then describing the usage was sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `str` on an object behaves like calling any other type: it calls `str.__new__` on your object, and then if the result is an instance of `str`, it calls `__init__` on the result.

`str.__new__` calls your `__str__` method, which returns a `MyEnum`. Since the return value is an instance of `str`, the next step is to call the `__init__` method. That's where the unexpected `__init__` call is coming from.

Comment: for myobject `a`, `str(a)` is not equivalent to `a.__str__()` but rather `str.__new__(a.__str__())` or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

@user2357112 has the right of it.

To elaborate on your points 2 and 3:

2. Why is it insufficient to return `self` since `self` is an `str`?

`self` is not a `str`, it's a `MyEnum` which is a `str` subclass -- a subclass that has it's own `__init__`, which then gets called.  The `str` class does not have an `__init__` method.

3. Why could I not implement this without setting "value"?

If `value` is not in `_init_`, then whatever is specified on the member line (and possibly modified by `_generate_next_value_`) is passed to `__new__` -- and `str`'s `__new__` takes three arguments, all of which are strings:

```
>>> help(str)
str(bytes_or_buffer[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str
```

which means that you would be doing

```
str(1, 2)
```

which would try to interpret `2` as an encoding.